# Find the longest duration during the machine is ON

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following **table** in **SQL Server**. I would like to find the longest duration for the machine running.

| Row | DateTime | Machine On |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/22/2022 8:20 | 1 |
| 2 | 9/22/2022 9:10 | 0 |
| 3 | 9/22/2022 10:40 | 1 |
| 4 | 9/22/2022 10:52 | 0 |
| 5 | 9/22/2022 12:30 | 1 |
| 6 | 9/22/2022 14:30 | 0 |
| 7 | 9/22/2022 15:00 | 1 |
| 8 | 9/22/2022 15:40 | 0 |
| 9 | 9/22/2022 16:25 | 1 |
| 10 | 9/22/2022 16:55 | 0 |

In the example above, the longest duration for the machine is ON is 2 hours using rows 5 and 6. What would be the best SQL statement that can provide the longest duration given a time range?

**Desired Result:**

60 minutes

I have looked into the LAG Function and the LEAD Function in SQL.

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: where is the data?

Comment: What's the expected result? (A [mcve] makes things much clearer.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that uses traditional gaps & islands methodology:

```
WITH src AS
(
  SELECT Island, mint = MIN([Timestamp]), maxt = MAX([Timestamp])
  FROM
  (
    SELECT [Timestamp], Island = 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp]) -
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Running ORDER BY [Timestamp])
    FROM dbo.Machine_Status
  ) AS x GROUP BY Island
)
SELECT TOP (1) delta = 
   (DATEDIFF(second, mint, LEAD(mint,1) OVER (ORDER BY island)))
 FROM src ORDER BY delta DESC;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l5rcJvWZ) based on the sample data in [your new duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75073621/61305).

Answer (score 1):

If this is really your data, you can simply use `INNER JOIN` and [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T1.[DateTime], T2.[DateTime]))
FROM [my_table] T1
INNER JOIN [my_table] T2
    ON T1.[Row] + 1 = T2.[Row];
```

Comment: This would also consider date differences between a row having machineon = 0 and the next row with machineon = 1 which seems to be incorrect. As I understand the question, only rows having machineon = 1 and the following row must be considered. Adding WHERE t1.machineon = 1 should solve this.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Yes, in order to be sure you are working with the correct rows you add `WHERE t1.machineon = 1` and even `t2.machineone = 0`, but the data seems already sorted and validated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem, one option to solve it is to use a running sum that increased by 1 whenever a machine_on = 0, this will define unique groups for consecutive 1s followed by 0.

```
select top 1 datediff(minute, min([datetime]), max([datetime])) duration
from
(
  select *, 
   sum(case when machine_on = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by datetime desc) grp
  from table_name
) T
group by grp
order by datediff(minute, min([datetime]), max([datetime])) desc
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xbfz6eZJ)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic Gaps and Islands with a little twist `Adj`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1
       Row1 = min(row)
      ,Row2 = max(row)+1
      ,TS1  = min(TimeStamp)
      ,TS2  = dateadd(SECOND,max(Adj),max(TimeStamp))
      ,Dur = datediff(Second,min(TimeStamp),max(TimeStamp)) + max(Adj)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = row_number() over( partition by Running order by TimeStamp) - row_number() over (order by timeStamp)
              ,Adj  = case when Running=1 and lead(Running,1) over (order by timestamp) = 0  then datediff(second,TimeStamp,lead(TimeStamp,1) over (order by TimeStamp) ) else 0 end
         From Machine_Status
      ) A
 Where Running=1
 Group By Grp
 Order By Dur Desc
```

**Results**

```
Row1    Row2    TS1                     TS2                       Dur
8       12      2023-01-10 08:25:30.000 2023-01-10 08:28:55.000   205
```