# Query for the longest duration of consecutive TRUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a machine logging the running status (True/False) to SQL Server every 1 minute unless there is a change of status. The table **Machine_Status** looks like this:

| Row | Timestamp | Running |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/10/2023 08:20:10 | 0 |
| 2 | 1/10/2023 08:21:10 | 0 |
| 3 | 1/10/2023 08:21:30 | 1 |
| 4 | 1/10/2023 08:22:30 | 1 |
| 5 | 1/10/2023 08:23:30 | 1 |
| 6 | 1/10/2023 08:23:40 | 0 |
| 7 | 1/10/2023 08:24:40 | 0 |
| 8 | 1/10/2023 08:25:30 | 1 |
| 9 | 1/10/2023 08:26:30 | 1 |
| 10 | 1/10/2023 08:27:30 | 1 |
| 11 | 1/10/2023 08:28:30 | 1 |
| 12 | 1/10/2023 08:28:55 | 0 |
| 13 | 1/10/2023 08:29:55 | 0 |

```
CREATE TABLE Machine_Status 
(
    Row INT,
    Timestamp   DateTime,
    Running Bit
);

INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('1', '1/10/2023 08:20:10', '0');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('2', '1/10/2023 08:21:10', '0');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('3', '1/10/2023 08:21:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('4', '1/10/2023 08:22:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('5', '1/10/2023 08:23:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('6', '1/10/2023 08:23:40', '0');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('7', '1/10/2023 08:24:40', '0');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('8', '1/10/2023 08:25:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('9', '1/10/2023 08:26:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('10', '1/10/2023 08:27:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('11', '1/10/2023 08:28:30', '1');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('12', '1/10/2023 08:28:55', '0');
INSERT INTO Machine_Status (Row, Timestamp, Running) VALUES ('13', '1/10/2023 08:29:55', '0');
```

My desired output is the longest duration the machine was running within a time range. With data from row 8 to 12, the result is 3 minutes + 25 seconds.

Desired Result:

| Longest Duration |
| --- |
| 205 seconds |

```
select max(datediff(second, t1.[Timestamp], t2.[Timestamp]))
from [Machine_Status] t1 inner join [Machine_Status] t2
on t1.[Row] <> t2.[Row];
```

The result from this is 585 which is not 205.

**Sorry, this is similar to my previous question but is not identical. This machine logs every minute unless there is status change. So it goes 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0, instead of flip flopping like the previous machine 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1.**

Comment: I actually don't see how this differs from your last question, so I've closed it as a duplicate of it. [Edit] your question if you feel that your prior question is not a duplicate, and provided you adequately **explain**  *why* this isn't a duplicate, I'll be happy to reopen the question.

Comment: The provided answers for the previous question still valid for this new requirement. [Check this demo for two of them](https://dbfiddle.uk/Maeen-XE)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter how many consecutive 1 values are there, the gaps and islands approaches to solve this problem will cover this issue.